# Simple Java mail program is not working?

Tags: java, email

I am wondering why the below basic java mail program is not working because I didn't get any errors as the program is executed just fine. Is there anything that I am doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.I would also like to add that I also tried it using wrong username and password combination but still getting no error and the programs runs completely fine.

```
public class emailfromgmail {

 public static void main(String[]args)
 {
    final String from = "username";
    final String pass = "password";
    String to = "recipient@gmail.com";
    String host="smtp.gmail.com";
    String subject = "java Mail";
    String body = "example of java mail api using gmail smtp";

 //get the session object

      Properties p = System.getProperties();
      p.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
      p.put("mail.smtp.host",host);
      p.put("mail.smtp.user",from);
      p.put("mail.smtp.password",pass );
      p.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
      p.put("mail.smtp.auth","true");

      Session session = Session.getInstance(p,
  new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(from, pass);
    }
  });

    try{
        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setText(body);

        Transport.send(msg);
        System.out.print("message sent successfully");

    }
    catch(MessagingException e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }     
 }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "it doesn't work"

Comment: Dear Sir actually I mean that the program is executing fine I did not get any errors but it just not doing anything I mean it is supposed to send the mail but it is not doing that.

Comment: Since the `from` value of the email message is not an email address, just a name, your message is likely discarded as spam. Try changing `from` to `sender@gmail.com`, where `sender` of course is your actual name.

Comment: Your code looks ok. No need to set the password in the `Properties` if you're already using `PasswordAuthentication` but it should work anyway. How do you know it is not sending the email? Isn't it printing `message sent successfully`? If it is printing that line, maybe the email went to spam or you're checking the wrong email account.

Comment: @Andreas Sir I don't think this is the problem it was mentioned in one of the answer I read over stackoverflow

Comment: @walen yes sir it does printing `message sent successfully` but it didn't send any mail to the inbox or in the spam of the recipient. p.s both account belongs to me

Comment: Just for cross checking I have also checked the sent folder of my gmail account. I didn't found any record which proves that mail was sent indeed

Comment: @PuneetSharma That's not a valid check, as emails in the sent folder are explicitly stored there by the client, there's usually no *connection* between the sending server (smtp service) and the incoming server (imap/pop3 service).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - I ran my program and put in a dialogue box in various places to see where it stopped doing anything. I still don't know what was wrong, but I tried a totally different approach and it worked. Instead of sending via TLS, I send via SSL. I used this website:

https://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/

Their TLS didn't work - it just didn't do anything when I ran it. Their SSL worked like a charm!

Here is the code:

```js
package com.mkyong.common;

import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class SendMailSSL {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Properties props = new Properties();
  props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
  props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
  props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
    "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
  props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
  props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

  Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
   new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
     return new PasswordAuthentication("username","password");
    }
   });

  try {

   Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
   message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from@no-spam.com"));
   message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
     InternetAddress.parse("to@no-spam.com"));
   message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
   message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler," +
     "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

   Transport.send(message);

   System.out.println("Done");

  } catch (MessagingException e) {
   throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
 }
}
```